# Grid Vs List Issue on Product Listing Page and Home Page

Tags: product, home

I am calling  a block of category on Homepage to show 5 product in a row. I have set the mode to "grid" for this block. But when I shift grid view to list view inside the site on Product listing page the home page also grid view is changing to the list view. I would like to restrict the block on homepage to "grid" view. Is there any solution for this? Please advise me.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this, but you should be able to set the block configuration on the home page via the layout/cms.xml to force grid mode like so:

```
        <action method="setData">
            <key>_current_grid_mode</key>
            <value>grid</value>
        </action>
```

So it could look something like this:

```
<!-- layout handle for the default homepage action -->
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_featured" name="product_featured">

            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>catalog/product/featured.phtml</template>
            </action>

            <action method="setCategoryId">
                <catId>1</catId>
            </action>

            <action method="setColumnCount">
                <count>5</count>
            </action>

            <action method="setData">
                <key>_current_grid_mode</key>
                <value>grid</value>
            </action>

        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```